# Unable to set logging level in python

Tags: python, logging

The following code and yaml configuration produce the warning message but not the debug message, run from either Eclipse/Pydev or from the command line.  With the print statement uncommented, the config dictionary looks good.  What am I missing?

setupLogging.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import logging.config
import yaml

def setupLogging():
    with open('loggingConfig.yaml', 'rt') as file:
        config = yaml.safe_load(file.read())
        #print(str(config))
        logging.config.dictConfig(config)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    setupLogging()
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.debug("logger debug")
    logger.warning("logger warning")
```

loggingConfig.yaml:

```
---

version: 1

disable_existing_loggers: False

formatters:

    simple:
        format: "%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"

handlers:
    console:
        class: logging.StreamHandler
        level: DEBUG
        formatter: simple
        stream: ext://sys.stdout

root:
    handlers: [console]

...
```

Comment: You need a level for root, this is per default: INFO

Comment: Thank you, you're right, adding "logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)" seems to have fixed the problem.  But the default is WARNING.